# Saving damaged HDD (Win10-Sys) on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive

Device with problem: Hard disk drive (1TB, internal, notebook, Windows 10)

Rootcause: physically damaged (something hit the notebook), BIOS asked for a bootable disk.

USB-Live-Stick worked perfectly with the notebook, conclusion -> problem only with HDD. When I tried to open/mount the HDD, an error-message occurred: ".. try in read-only mode.."

1. Goal: recover data
2. Goal: save the disk (if possible)

Solutions tried so far:

1. Windows-Recovery-USB-Stick created with another Windows 10
2. Start-help: unsuccessful. Recoverypoint: unsuccessful.
3. "chkdsk /f /r" with runtime of around 48 hours: unknown error 6e74667363686b2e b05 at 99% of phase 4 (I guess, since 5 is on empty space) and 10% or 11% overall
4. connected to another notebook with Linux Mint via USB to S-ATA
5. I can read the HDD via "disks" (see picture)
   ['disks' on Linux Mint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQABg.png)
6. "sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda4 /media/winhdd" with no response (had to abort with CTRL+C, tried ..sda1.. as well)

How to proceed next?

EDIT: Since this question has been marked as "exact duplicate of an existing question" I am asked to "explain how it is different". How can I see the question which seems to be alike?

EDIT2: Ok, saw it on top of mine now, will review it's answers and come back afterwards. Please give me some time to do this.

Comment: Can you clone the drive/partition(s) using clonezilla? If not, and you need the data off, then maybe a recovery company such as http://www.vogon-data-recovery.co.uk/

Comment: I would make clone (or image file) with `ddrescue` and work with it, not the original disk. But this is the thing to do *first*, not next; and it requires you to have another disk at least as large as the original.